# Export data and symbology from QGIS to ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro, export

I have tried exporting, from QGIS 3.30.2, a shapefile together with symbology. I have tried with a GeoPackage and as a shapefile.

After export it seems that no symbology is preserved (Categorised).

Is there a way to export this and to get this into ArcGis Pro?

(Maybe just to take files from connection)

Comment: Shapefiles don't hold symbology so using that as a format wouldn't work.  GeoPackage does though so it would be a better choice.

Comment: @nmtoken true but ArcGIS doesn't recognise symbology stored in GeoPackages unfortunately.

Comment: You can export your symbolized shapefile to a qml style file and use that to easily apply symbology to a layer (whatever the data type) in another QGIS project.  ArcGIS cannot use the qml.  You can export your symbolized shapefile to a qlr and when you add that to a QGIS project it will add the shapefile and symbolize it if the shapefile is in the same path location.  ArcGIS cannot use qlr.  If a rasterized version of your categorized shapefile is OK you could create a layout and export to a georeferenced pdf.  ArcGIS can't use a pdf directly but it can convert the pdf to a geotiff.

Answer (score 2):

Ah the painful world of symbology. Unfortunately there is no easy way of migrating from QGIS to ArcGIS while preserving symbology. In QGIS you can save a layer's default symbology into a geopackage however this will only work when you open it in QGIS. Shapefiles don't ever preserve symbology.

The **SLYR: the ESRI to QGIS Compatibility Suite** (https://north-road.com/slyr/) may be able to help you. I believe it was originally developed to help bring symbology from ArcGIS to QGIS (opposite way to what you want to do) but it now may have some capabilities to move the other direction also, however I can't attest to it personally as I haven't used it myself.

Comment: You could ask ESRI to support SLD and open symbology encoding standard that they voted to accept at the OGC.

Comment: Looking at my copy of SLYR there are tools to `Convert QGIS style XML to STYLX` and `Convert QGS to MAPX`  for ArcGIS Pro